# Angular ~ Property '' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular

Some days ago I have started working on an Angular project, and how my "infrastructure" works is: Angular (front-end) connects to the node.js server (back-end) which if needed sends a request or query to an api server or a mongo database.

Now.. the response of **node.js** back to Angular is formatted as `json` so an example could be `(response = { "date": getDate() } )`. The problem comes with how can I access that response or more specifically.. access the date child? This is how I did it:

```js
let url = "http://localhost:3000/checkdate"
this.http.post(url, data).subscribe((responsedata) => {
   console.log(responsedata.date);
})
```

The the 3th line is where the error stays at, and it says "***Property 'date' does not exist on type 'Object'.***", anyone who can help me with it?

Also if you need, this is what I did with node.js to send a response back formatted as json:

```
app.post("/checkdate", (req, res) => {
    console.log("New post request recieved!");
    res.json({
        "date": "12.31.2000"
    })
})
```

I really don't seem to find a way or answer on the internet to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Can you console.log your response from the server and post it here?

Comment: Yeah sure (output is 12.31.2000)! The strangest thing i have noticed is that even if it says "Property date...." the application works perfectly for some reason, i just want to ignore or fix this error in some way...

Comment: If you are sending a JSON object from the server then console.log should print a JSON object right? Can you post that here?

Comment: Yes it prints: Object { date: "12.31.2000" } to the console

Comment: I can see no problem accessing the date object. it should be simply accessed as responsedata.date

Comment: i knowwww but for some reason it just throws that error randomly, and its not problem of the ide cuz when i start the angular app with "ng serve --open" it also warns me about this error

Comment: It’s just a type error. You can fix it by doing (responsedata: any)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try responseData.obj.date?

Comment: nnope always the same result: Property 'obj' does not exist on type 'Object'